# Word Wrap on Magento Invoice

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, name

I am working on this file:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php
```

I have products with long names.
For Example product name is:

**loonggggg producttttt nameeeee**

I want it like this on the Invoice:

**longggggg produc...**

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

Try this way:

```
$this->helper('core/string')->truncate($product->getName(), 65,'...', $_reminder, false);
```

Here `$product` is an object and `65` is letter count. You can try with increasing/decreasing it as per your need.

Hope this helps.

**Ref: Take a look at this file/function**

```
//code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/String.php

public function truncate($string, $length = 80, $etc = '...', &$remainder = '', $breakWords = true)
    {
        $remainder = '';
        if (0 == $length) {
            return '';
        }

        $originalLength = $this->strlen($string);
        if ($originalLength > $length) {
            $length -= $this->strlen($etc);
            if ($length <= 0) {
                return '';
            }
            $preparedString = $string;
            $preparedlength = $length;
            if (!$breakWords) {
                $preparedString = preg_replace('/\s+?(\S+)?$/u', '', $this->substr($string, 0, $length + 1));
                $preparedlength = $this->strlen($preparedString);
            }
            $remainder = $this->substr($string, $preparedlength, $originalLength);
            return $this->substr($preparedString, 0, $length) . $etc;
        }

        return $string;
    }
```